# maximum line count in node js : child-process.exec

Tags: node.js, git, large-data, child-process

### question

Do Node's `child-process` have a limit ?
And how can I do to fetch (chunk by chunk) a HUGE command output like git show with a huge file ?

---

### general problem

I try to parse results of `git show <commit sha>` and there is a **HUGE file** (308 344 lines)

when running `git show > showed_by_git.txt` i have the right output, with all the files, and a result of 118 667 lines

when running node's `child-process` i only retrieve 32 602 lines ...

---

### my test and its result

I simplified my code and used `child-process` to count the number of chars and the number of lines
it resolves before stopping the flow.

the result shows that it stops at 32 000+ lines instead of expected 118 667

You can reproduce this at home if you have a repository with some HUUUGE file **that has been commited recently**

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process')

function fetchCommand (command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sub = childProcess.exec(command)

    let chars = 0
    let lines = 0

    sub.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
      chars += chunk.length
      lines += chunk.split('\n').length
      console.log('chars:' + chars + ' lines:' + lines)
      // logs the char and line count on each chunk of data, 
      // then 'forgets' the data : no memory overloading
    })
    sub.stdout.on('close', function () {
      console.log('CLOSED')
    })
    sub.stderr.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message)
    })
  })
}

fetchCommand('git show').catch(err => console.log(err))
```

#### output

Here is the output :

```
C:\Users\guill\.code\git2stats>node examples/fetchTest.js
chars:4096 lines:126
chars:73728 lines:2117
chars:131072 lines:3772
chars:176128 lines:5176
chars:229376 lines:6560
chars:262144 lines:7663
chars:323584 lines:9171
chars:393216 lines:11304
chars:462848 lines:13483
chars:475136 lines:13849
chars:507904 lines:14916
chars:536576 lines:15839
chars:573440 lines:17028
chars:618496 lines:18484
chars:688128 lines:20539
chars:737280 lines:22000
chars:765952 lines:22930
chars:794624 lines:23860
chars:823296 lines:24794
chars:892928 lines:26976
chars:962560 lines:29104
chars:991232 lines:30003
chars:1032192 lines:31292
chars:1073152 lines:32602
CLOSED
```

You can see that it stops at 32 602 lines, whereas this particular `git show` has 118 667 lines to show

#### the last chunk

I checked the last chunk of data to see if it did something special about the big file,
but I can confirm **it stops right in the middle of the file**

---

### context

I am writing a
[git statistics tools](https://github.com/gui3/git2stats),
this program is on a very good way
since I could parse `git log --stat`
then `git show <commit sha>` for each commit
and return a satisfying json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some kind of Node foot-gun that I was previously unaware of.

Yes, there is a limit. It is configured with the `maxBuffer` option ([see docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)), which can be set to Infinity if you like. The idea that this can be set to Infinity is not documented.

```
const sub = childProcess.exec(command, { maxBuffer: Infinity });
```

I am honestly shocked that this limit exists, and I will now be force to do a code review across a large body of code to find every place where the `child_process` module is used and see if I need to add a `maxBuffer` option.

Consider it an example of how to design an interface poorly.

### Minor note

You probably want to handle `sub.on('exit', code => {})` or `sub.on('close')` which is the same thing, so you can check the exit status of Git and raise an error if the status is not 0. Something like this:

```
sub.on('exit', code => {
    if (code == 0) {
        resolve(...);
    } else {
        reject(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry you have to do a code review ... thanks a lot, i'll give it a try with `maxBuffer: Infinity` . Anyways, I realize that I should ignore huge files by default if i want to protect against possible memory issues/ process time issues.